# Remove double quotes

Tags: python

I am create an app in which I need to read from PDF file to Python contain `'Casa','Perro','Gato'`.

```
    reader = PdfReader('media/words.pdf')
    page = reader.pages[0]
   
    self.extract = page.extract_text()
    print(self.extract)
```

The result is `["'Casa','Perro','Gato'"]`

How could I remove the outer string `" "`? I need the result `['Casa','Perro','Gato']`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ast.literal_eval` after removing slicing off some characters from both ends to produce a list.

```py
from ast import literal_eval
res = literal_eval(f'[{self.extract[2:-2]}]')
```

If you just need a string result, you can directly replace all double quotes

```py
res = self.extract.replace('"', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need one-liner solution without a library, here it is:

```py
# First way
result = [i.replace("'",'') for i in self.extract[0].split(',')]
print(result)
# Second way
result = self.extract[0].replace("'",'').split(',')
print(result)
```